# Gif black background when rotated

Tags: php, gif

So how can i rotate an GIF image without making the black background appear to the image using PHP:s imagerotate?

I've been trying for hours and it still wont work. Here is what i got sofar :

```
        $degrees = 90.0;

        if($size['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
            $rotate = imagecreatefromgif($viewFile);
            $rotate = imagerotate($rotate, $degrees, imagecolorallocatealpha($rotate, 0, 0, 0, 127), 0);
            imagealphablending($rotate, false);
            imagesavealpha($rotate, true);
            if ($rotate != false) {
                imagegif($rotate, $viewFile, 100);
            }
            else {
                exit();
            }
        }
```

i have tried all i can think of based on this.. PNG files are working well, it's only the GIF:s that wont work.

Comment: You need to use `imagecolortransparent` - Try using/incorporating something like this `$im = imagecreatefromgif("beachball1.gif"); 
$white = imagecolorexact($im, 255, 255, 255); 
imagecolortransparent($im, $white);` - Source: http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=91628

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Thanks for the answer, sadly it's still the same.